# How to Run iPhone Frame in iPad Mini?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Back when the iPad generation was first out, I remember a setting which allowed you to shrink the screen to iPhone resolution. It would fill in the remaining portions of the screen with just black, allowing the screen to look like you're running an iPhone on the iPad.

Is this still possible?

Comment: You should still be able to do this with an iPad mini. The thing is that if your app is made for iPad (like, a universal: both) you'll have the iPad version.

Comment: @Larme Right. So is there a way to force the iPhone layout?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's designed like this. If an app was made with an iPad design, we can assume it's more adapted to big screens.

Comment: @Larme Could have swore that I had an app run in the iPhone size before... (And it wasn't an iPhone-only app)